# WPF - How do I reuse data templates of singular object for collection?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

As I was creating a data type - control mapping for my application, I found out that it is feasible by using ContentPresenter and Data Templates. I have successfully done that. For this snippet, I included the mapping for System.String data type. However, I noticed that if I bound a list of strings and mapped a generic collection control for it, the strings are represented as a TextBox rather as just plain string as shown in the figure below (See StringCollection)!

[image]

Now, I wish to use this leverage in order to re-use the control when the dynamic PropertyValue is assigned with a collection. How can I implement the multi-binding for the TextBox? If the PropertyValue is an array, then bind to its elements; else bind to the PropertyValue itself.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel x:Name="ItemStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="8">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyName}" FontSize="14" MinWidth="120"
            Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}">
        </TextBlock>
        <ContentPresenter Margin="48, 0, 0, 0" Content="{Binding PropertyValue}">
            <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type System:String}">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=ItemStackPanel, Path=DataContext.PropertyValue}" 
                        Width="100" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ErrorTemplate}">
                    </TextBox>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type dataTypes:StringCollection}">
                    <controls:GenericCollectionControl x:Name="GenericCollectionControl"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ItemStackPanel, Path=DataContext.PropertyValue}"
                        Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ErrorTemplate}">
                    </controls:GenericCollectionControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentPresenter.Resources>
        </ContentPresenter>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

--- Revision 1 ---

I managed to make it work by utilizing a IMultiValueConverter and return the correct binding.

```
<TextBox Width="100" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ErrorTemplate}">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BindingSelector}">
            <Binding Mode="OneWay"></Binding>
            <Binding ElementName="ItemStackPanel" Path="DataContext.PropertyValue"></Binding>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

But I'm having an exception if the binding mode is not one way. How can I achieve two-way binding for this?

Answer (score 0):

> But I'm having an exception if the binding mode is not one way. How can I achieve two-way binding for this?

Try to specify a path for the first binding:

```
<TextBox Width="100" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ErrorTemplate}">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BindingSelector}">
            <Binding Path="." />
            <Binding ElementName="ItemStackPanel" Path="DataContext.PropertyValue"></Binding>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: What does Path="." mean?

Comment: It means that you are binding to the DataContext itself which I believe is the string in your case. A explicit path is required for two-way bindings.